# Navbar dropdown not displaying properly

Tags: html, css

I want the dropdown on my navbar to be wide enough the the text in it displays properly, but it's constrained to the size of the button you hover over to activate it. I want the dropdown to be a bigger width than the button.

The title displays fine in browser so not too sure why it is misaligned in the fiddle.

```css
#center-title {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
#cog {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#dropdown {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
#dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0#2);
}
#dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
#dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
#dropdown:hover #dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
nav {
  background-color: #2b569a;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="center">
    <h1 id="center-title"> Blocs </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="dropdown">
    <img id="cog" src="/static/images/cog2.png" alt="" />
    <div id="dropdown-content">
      <a href="profile.html"> Profile </a>
      <a href="settings.html"> Settings </a>
      <a href="logs.html"> Logs </a>
      <a href="emails.html"> Email list </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: you don't have any CSS for your `center` class?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid given the description of the issue, I wouldn't worry about the `.center` class missing. It's more interesting that the JSFiddle and pasted code are not the same.

Comment: @hungerstar Where are you seeing that they aren't the same?

Comment: You have `nav{overflow:hidden;}` in the JSFiddle. That won't help.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid the pasted code and the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55qggpbg/) do not have the same code. Compare `nav` and the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `right: 0;` to `#dropdown-content`.

```css
#center-title {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
#cog {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#dropdown {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
#dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0#2);
}
#dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
#dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
#dropdown:hover #dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
nav {
  background-color: #2b569a;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="center">
    <h1 id="center-title"> Blocs </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="dropdown">
    <img id="cog" src="/static/images/cog2.png" alt="" />
    <div id="dropdown-content">
      <a href="profile.html"> Profile </a>
      <a href="settings.html"> Settings </a>
      <a href="logs.html"> Logs </a>
      <a href="emails.html"> Email list </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:flex,instead of using float's and display:inline-block for layouts.

check this snippet

```css
. #center-title {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
#cog {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.center {
  margin: auto;
}
#dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  right: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0#2);
}
#dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
#dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
#dropdown:hover #dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
nav {
  background-color: #2b569a;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="center">
    <h1 id="center-title"> Blocs </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="dropdown">
    <img id="cog" src="/static/images/cog2.png" alt="" />
    <div id="dropdown-content">
      <a href="profile.html"> Profile </a>
      <a href="settings.html"> Settings </a>
      <a href="logs.html"> Logs </a>
      <a href="emails.html"> Email list </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Hope it helps